# More graceful solution to nested Linq queries?

Tags: c#, linq, refactoring

I have a set of nested linq queries that are used to get a property from a list of properties. It works great as-is, but it has one caveat. I have to put in error handling just in-case there isn't a suitable match. Is there are similar method of accomplishing what the following code does without having to use a try-catch block?

```
try
{
    organization =
    _orgs.FirstOrDefault(n => 
        n.OrganizationFields.FirstOrDefault(nn => 
            nn.Key == "customer_id").Value.ToString() == id);
}
catch (InvalidOperationException)
{
    return null;
}
catch (NullReferenceException)
{
    return null;
}
```

Comment: Is Organization one-to-many with OrganizationFields? If that's the case then you could start your query with _orgs.OrganizationFields(where clause on id).Select(n => n._org).FirstOrDefault(); If there are no matches that should return null without causing an exception

Comment: firstordefault does not throw InvalidOperationException by itself. it seems in your code that exception would never happen(if you dont throw that in getter of properties). so that catch is useless.

Comment: @M.kazemAkhgary `_orgs` or `OrganizationFields` or `.ToString()` could all throw null reference exceptions :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using C# 6, you can use the [Null Conditional Operator](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dn986595.aspx).

```
organization =
_orgs?.FirstOrDefault(n => 
    n.OrganizationFields?.FirstOrDefault(nn => 
        nn.Key == "customer_id")?.Value.ToString() == id);
```

Here's a complete program that shows it in action

```
class Bar
{
    public string Text { get; set; }
}

class Foo
{
    public List<Bar> Bars { get; set; }
}

class Program
{
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        Foo foo = new Foo(); // Note that foo.Bars is still null

        string text = foo.Bars?.FirstOrDefault()?.Text;

        Console.WriteLine(text);
    }
}
```

Comment: Unfortunately I get an error on the `?` before `.Value` saying that `...Can't apply operand to type... KeyValuePair`

Comment: @Jdsfighter Are you using C#6?

Comment: Yes I am. All the other `?` operators worked. Just not the one before `Value`

Comment: @Jdsfighter Oh right - yes, `KeyValuePair<TKey,TValue>` is a non-nullable struct. You can remove the `?` in this case, as it's guaranteed to not be null.

Comment: It turns out it was the `Value` portion that was actually null. By moving the `?` operand over between `Value` and `ToString` the error has been fixed.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure why you need to catch `InvalidOperationException`, so I'll ignore it. What about `NullReferenceException`, I assume it can only be generated by the `FirstOrDefault(...).Value` call (if you follow the best practices, none of the `_orgs`, `n.OrganizationFields` or `Value` should be `null`).

If the above assumptions are correct, the following should be the equivalent of the sample code w/o a need of exception handlers

```
organization = _orgs.FirstOrDefault(n => n.OrganizationFields
    .Any(nn => nn.Key == "customer_id" && nn.Value.ToString() == id));
```

As per your comment, if the `Value` can be `null`, then either use `nn.Value?.ToString() == ...` in C#6, or `nn.Value != null && nn.Value.ToString() == ...` in pre C#6.

Comment: The `InvalidOperationException` is a holdover from when I was using `First` instead of `FirstOrDefault`.

Comment: Your solution works when I change `nn.Value.ToString()` to be `nn.Value?.ToString()`. It looks like it was the `Value` property that was null.

Comment: Well, that was an assumption I mentioned, since you didn't provide enough information. Anyway.